# React-bootstrap modal displaying invalid characters in 'x' mark

Tags: react-bootstrap

We are using react-modal to display modal dialog and we have the following code

```
<Modal.Header closeButton>
     <Modal.Title>Drugs</Modal.Title>
</Modal.Header>
```

The close button appears as in the attached image. Anyone faced the same issue before?[Close Button issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYLW9.png)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a meta tag to set your encoding to UTF-8:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/2098

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessarily elegant, but here is a solution. I'm using React/Redux, so on my container I mapped the following function from my dispatch to props:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    ...

    fixCloseLabel: function(e) {
      e.getElementsByClassName('modal-header')[0].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML = 'x'
    }

    ...
}
```

Then on the modal itself I just added the following:

```
<Modal show={this.props.twitterModalVisible} onEnter={this.props.fixCloseLabel} onHide={this.props.hideTwitterModal}>
```

Just make sure you pass your props down the chain and you should be good to go!